# On the grammaticality of "What it is that you fear is unfounded."

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs, subjects

Is the construction

> What it is that you fear is unfounded.

grammatically correct?
I am somewhat confused about what the subject of the first auxilary *is* is. Is it *what*, or is it *it*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is grammatical:

> [My doubt] is unfounded.
>   [Their belief] is unfounded.
>   [The thing I'm ashamed of] is unfounded.
>
> [What it is you fear] is unfounded.

In all of those sentences, the words in square brackets form the subject.

---

> What do you fear?

In that sentence, the subject is *what*.

But in *what it is that you fear*, it's the entire phrase that's the subject.

The phrase could be expanded into something much larger, and the entire thing would still remain the subject:

> [What it is you fear that will come back one day to haunt you after you've come home from work and eaten a big meal] is unfounded.

All of the additional words combine to make up the entirety of the subject. It's neither *what* nor *is*, but everything in the square brackets.

It's the same thing as the following:

> [The ball that rolled down the hill and gathered moss] was large.